# Determine source of transitive dependency

Tags: gradle

I have a project in which I am using sl4j with log4j. I recently added a few new dependencies to my project, and one of these new dependencies that I added is including a transitive dependency to logback-classic, which includes another binding for sj4j.

I want to get rid of logback, but I have no clue which of my direct dependencies added the transitive dependency so that I can exclude it.

In maven I know how to get the entire graph of dependencies to determine which is the source of a transitive dependency, but I have no clue of how to do this with gradle.

Does anyone knows how to get the source dependency of a transitive dependency with gradle?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To show the whole dependency tree for each class path, use:

```
> gradle dependencies
```

If you are only interested in a particular *class path*, use (say):

```
> gradle dependencies --configuration compile
```

Use the `-p` option to run on a sub-project.

To show who pulls in a particular dependency onto a particular class path, and how any version conflicts were resolved, use (say):

```
> gradle dependencyInsight --dependency logback --configuration compile
```

---

Note that you can also exclude a dependency from a whole class path (or multiple). Usually this is more reliable than excluding a particular transitive dependency. For example:

```
configurations.all*.exclude module: "logback-classic"
```

Answer (score 2):

An updated answer:

I used this code to resolve a dependency issue between logback and log4j:

```js
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl') using module ('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3')
    }
}
```

This solution finds any dependencies on log4j-slf4j-impl and instructs it to choose the one from logback (this is a spring app). This solution was surprisingly difficult to track down, but likely very useful in many situations.

Here's the gradle documentation on [handling conflicting candidates](http://configurations.all%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20substitute%20module(%27org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl%27)%20using%20module%20(%27ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3%27)%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D).