# react native gradlew assembleRelease failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, slf4j

Your Environment

```
Plugin version: 2.5.6
Platform: Android
OS version: windows

React Native version: 0.63.2
```

Context

when i want to build a apk or run my project with react-native run android it fail because of conflict between @mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation and react-native-linear-gradient and when i delete one of them every thing run perfectly
Expected Behavior

i like to generate a apk for my application or run it on my device but ...
Actual Behavior

this is the error it gave me

Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

```
1 exception was raised by workers:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder found in modules logback-android-1.1.1-9-runtime.jar (com.github.tony19:logback-android:1.1.1-9) and slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder found in modules logback-android-1.1.1-9-runtime.jar (com.github.tony19:logback-android:1.1.1-9) and slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder found in modules logback-android-1.1.1-9-runtime.jar (com.github.tony19:logback-android:1.1.1-9) and slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25)
```

Possible Fix

i want to know how can i resolve the conflict for this org.slf4j

@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation is using slf4j 1.7.25
and react-native-linear-gradient is using slf4j 1.7.21
or vice versa i don't remember correctly

Comment: Looks like a conflict with `org.slf4j:slf4j-simple`. Is that a transitive dependency?

Comment: @tony19 i really don't know that is  transitive dependency or not. is there any way that i can fix this?

Comment: If they're not listed in your normal dependencies, then it's likely transitive. You could [configure your build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657539/determine-source-of-transitive-dependency) to exclude `slf4j-simple` or `logback-android`.